# Currency Exchange API Java GUI

Tags: java, api, rest, currency

I am fairly new to programming of this level and I was wondering if someone could help me with this.

So I am trying to create a currency exchange app using Java, and I have a problem updating the values on the GUI to reflect the new value on the API. Essentially ever so often the values change and it shows on the console, however, the GUI value never updates and stays the same.

I thought ActionListener would help solve this problem but either I have not implemented it properly or I haven't googled and come up with a solution properly.

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Here is my code:
GUI.java

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {
    
    static Arb arb = new Arb();

    private JPanel contentPane;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                 try {
                    arb.runUpdate_fx("anAPI");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
         };
         Timer timer = new Timer(100 ,taskPerformer);
         timer.setRepeats(true);
         timer.start();
 
         Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI frame = new GUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public GUI() {
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setBounds(100, 100, 1121, 765);
      contentPane = new JPanel();
      contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
      setContentPane(contentPane);

      JTextPane FXRate = new JTextPane();
      FXRate.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
      FXRate.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
      FXRate.setEditable(false);
      FXRate.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
      panel_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 5, 5));
      FXRate.setText("FX Rates\r\n\r\nEUR-AUD FX Rate: " + arb.fxEURAUD + "\r\nEUR-USD FX Rate: " + arb.fxEURUSD);
      panel_1.add(FXRate);
    }
}
```

Result:
EUR-AUD: 1.646659
**after sometime**
EUR-AUD: 1.646659

Expected Result:
EUR-AUD: 1.646659
**after sometime**
EUR-AUD: 1.80102

Comment: Well, you *never* update your UI anywhere. You need to call FXRate.setText("My new string"); to set a new text on it. You never do, after setting the initial string.

Comment: Dwarsaw, I've taken the liberty of editing out the data.fixer.io API key you included in your request. Most likely this is accidental, but you should take utmost care to NEVER publish any API keys to any service anywhere in public. This includes in Github source code and in Stack Overflow questions. Leaving such APÏ keys publicly exposed can allow others to make requests in your name and potentially cost you A LOT of money in service costs.

Comment: @Nzall Gotcha, i just signed up for a free account and didn't really bother much with it but thank you, will take not of it in the future.

Comment: @Polygnome do you mean just setting a global String variable and having it update in main?

Comment: @Dwarsaw No. Updating the contents of the variable simply does not update the text on the panel. you literally need to call `JTextPane.SetText("my New String")`; to set another text. references are passed by value, not as pointer.

Comment: @Polygnome trying that really made me go woah, thats cool. Thank you very much poly, Is it cool if I ask you a question or two more?

Comment: @Dwarsaw If you have another question, please open a new question.

Comment: @Polygnome gotcha! Was gonna ask something along the lines of would my code here be considered good practice. I still have a lot to learn and I will do as you said :)

Comment: @Dwarsaw You might want to check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Cool, I'll check it out, ty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*References are passed by value* in Java.

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
String text = "Initial text";
textField.setText(text); // no displays "Initial text";
text = "Updated text"; // doesn't change what the panel displays
// the panel still holds a reference to the old text
textField.setText(text); // updates the reference the panel holds to your new text
```

In your event listener, you need to call `setText` *with the updated string* to actually make the textfield display that.

Answer (score 0):

Your timer and event handler look good, but the update method only fetches new values into the Arb object; nothing takes those values and puts them into the GUI. You can do that explicitly in your event handler.after the update method returns. To enable that, you may want to make FXRate a member variable, so you can access it from the action listener.

Comment: Is creating a member variable essentially just creating a variable global/static to GUI.java?

Comment: @Dwarsaw Yes, in the sense that I believe you understand the task, but no, in the sense that your language is wrong (Java has no globals, and “static” means something else); but yes, creating a variable in the scope of the GUI class body.

Comment: So if I got this right, there is no global variable but you can have public variables which can be referenced by other classes correct? And static is specific to the class and quite literally "static" in a sense correct?

Comment: I can’t really go over all the details here, but yes, public member variables exist in the scope of a class or object, and are visible to all other code. “Static” members (public or not) are scoped to the class, and shared by all instances of that class, while non-static members belong to each individual instance. Avoid public and static both, unless you actually need them.